# Jquery animate, execute opposite action if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to animate divs. The idea is that when the customer has scrolled until the div it become animated... and if the customer scroll back to the top of the page this the div run the action opposite to the first animation (like a fadein/out)

Well the point is that after the first animation, the second one never run.

This is my code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="face_content">
  <img src="img/face.jpg">
 </div>
 <div class="face_text">
  <p>some text here</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

And then I am trying this javascript with jquery

```
var face_dist = $('.wrapper').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function () {
 //show the face
 var face_diff = face_dist - $(window).scrollTop();
 if(face_diff < 200) {
  show_sch();
 }

 if($('.face_content').hasClass('showing')) {
  if(face_diff > 200) {
   hide_sch();
  }
 }
});

function show_sch() {
    $('.face_content img').animate({
        'opacity': 1,
        'right': 0
    },1000, function() {
        $('.face_content').addClass('showing');
    });
    $('.face_text ul').animate({
        'opacity': 1,
        'left': 0
    },1000);
}

function hide_sch() {
    $('.face_content img').animate({
        'opacity': 0,
        'right': 80
    },1000);
    $('.face_text ul').animate({
        'opacity': 0,
        'left': 80
    },1000);
}
```

Any idea? (the first animation run properly but the second one no at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because your `face_diff` value is never more than 200, but smaller than -200. And you animate is played a lot of time. You can control this with a check if active.

Please try below

```js
var face_dist = $('.wrapper').offset().top;
var active = 0; 
$(window).scroll(function () {
 //show the face
 var face_diff = face_dist - $(window).scrollTop();
 if(face_diff < 200 && face_diff >= 0) {
   if(active==0){
      active=1;
      show_sch();
    }
  
 }

 if($('.face_content').hasClass('showing')) {
  if(face_diff < -200) {
   if(active==0){
      active=1;
      hide_sch();
    }
  }
 }
});

function show_sch() {
    $('.face_content img').animate({
        'opacity': 1,
        'right': 0
    },1000, function() {
      $('.face_content').addClass('showing');
      active=0;
    });
    $('.face_text ul').animate({
        'opacity': 1,
        'left': 0
    },1000,function(){
      active=0;
    });
}

function hide_sch() {
    $('.face_content img').animate({
        'opacity': 0,
        'right': 80
    },1000,function(){
       active=0;
    });
    $('.face_text ul').animate({
        'opacity': 0,
        'left': 80
    },1000,function(){
      active=0;
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="face_content">
  <img style="opacity:0" src="https://www.dpreview.com/files/p/articles/7192167506/images/intro.jpeg">
 </div>
 <div class="face_text">
  <p>some text here</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: oh you edited this haha... i was trying and was going to said No working but now I tried again and is running!!! is all about that variable (active) you added!!